# How to export all local signatures

Tags: gnupg

I have 2 separate keyrings and would like to transfer all public keys and the corresponding signatures I have made to my other key.

~ 10 years ago I created a Master key on an offline computer with both a signing and encryption subkey.

I ended up not using the subkey because I started using gpg4win on an online computer with a different keyring and have since collected > 40 signatures and locally signed them all.

I would like to now start using my old key that has been offline for 10 years however I do not want to rebuild all of the public keys I have collected and signed.

I think the best thing to do is to export all the public keys with a local signature and then with the offline key ultimately trust my gpg4win key. Then generate a revoke certificate for the online gpg4win key and stop using it.

the `gpg --export`command doesn't seem to let me export ALL of the public keys.

Please let me know your thoughts and/or if there is a more elegant solution to transfer my keyring to my old, offline, key.

Answer (score 3):

There are several other ways, but `--export-options export-local-sigs` is the most direct answer.

(You will have to specify `--import-options import-local-sigs` later as well.)